# How socket.io emit to room that start with some keywords

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

How to emit to a room that starts with a keyword. like

// as I have 3 room named game1,game2,chat1

io.emit(\game.\g,"hello")

//expect sent to game1,game2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**STEPS:**

1. Push your rooms into an array.
2. Filter the rooms by keyword.
3. Iterate through the filtered rooms.
4. Emit to each of them.

```js
let keyword = 'game';
const rooms = ['game1','game2','chat1'];
let filteredRooms = rooms.filter(room => room.indexOf(keyword) > -1);
filteredRooms.forEach(filteredRoom => {
  console.log(filteredRoom);
  // io.emit(filteredRoom, "hello");
});
```